# does redeclaration of a variable in function and main dom?

Tags: javascript

If I have declared a variable, do I have to redeclare it when using it in a function, 
for example:

```
let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
display.prototype.clear = function () {
  let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
  libraryForm.reset();
}
```

do I have to do this or this function is correct:

```
let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
display.prototype.clear = function () {
  libraryForm.reset();
}
```

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do/achieve. But this should be a topic on most/every JavaScript tutorial when they talk about variables and their scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If the element exists when the outer line runs, and that element will always remain in the DOM, then you can save a reference to the variable and use it in the function, like in your lower code.

Often this is achievable, and is probably preferable, but it's not always possible. Sometimes, you'll have to select the element inside the function. For example, if the element gets replaced with another of the same ID, you'll have to re-select it. Here's an example of where failing to re-select the element will result in a bug:

```js
const libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
const clear = function() {
  libraryForm.reset();
};

// If something corrupts the container, then the element stored in the variable above
// will no longer be in the DOM
container.innerHTML += '';

// and the following line will fail:
clear();

// oops... the form we reset isn't in the DOM anymore
console.log(libraryForm.isConnected);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form id="libraryForm">
  </form>
</div>
```

You'll also have to select the element inside the function if it doesn't exist when the outer line runs, for example:

```html
<script>
const libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
const clear = function() {
  libraryForm.reset();
};

setTimeout(clear, 2000);
</script>
<div id="container">
  <form id="libraryForm">
  </form>
</div>
```

(though in the above case, it'd be good to put your `script` in a separate file and use the `defer` attribute, or wrap everything in a DOMContentLoaded listener)